# How call open fileupload dialog file after click?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

There is a click event inside that is defined a class of clicked element via switch case:

```
...
case 'icon_4':
    elemInside = 'photo';
    return false;
break;
```

How I can call dialog window **fileupload** for selecting local files?
Use File Upload Plugin.

The form with a input file is loaded by AJAX after click:

```
<div class="photo itm">
    <input type="file" id="sharePhotoPublic">
    <div id="files" class="outputFiles"></div>
</div>
```

This type solution have not helped:

```
$('#sharePhotoPublic').click();
```

Comment: Which File Upload Plugin?

Comment: Yes - https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: The last time that I checked blueimp's file upload UI, he had a CSS style sheet that made the file upload input larger, placed it over the "click" button, and then made it invisible. Have you tried with Firebug or another HTML debugger to see whether this is happening on your form?